# The straightest possible path embeddable in a path of polygons

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

I'm studying a problem involving the sets of discrete curves that can be embedded in a non-trivial polygon, from a source to a target point, as shown below.

[image: Paths through a tunnel or sequence of polygons]

Initially my interest was limited to the set containing discrete curves with the possible smallest segment count and within this set the discrete curve with the shortest length. I've been able to find this discrete curve (not shown in the above graphic).

Now I'm considering the problem of the straightest-possible discrete curve that can be embedded in the polygon, and I suspect, or rather I'm hoping, that both curves, the one with the smallest segment count and the straightest one are identical. I'd appreciate help showing that is or isn't the case.

Note: I'm aware of the concept of geodesics as shortest possible paths. However, the curve I'm studying isn't the shortest path but the path with the smallest segment count. In the example provided above, the shortest path would cut around corners as it seeks to minimize the path length. Interestingly, this curving of the path increases its segment count.

**Clarification of the question** (*courtesy of arex*)

Suppose a simple polygon is given, along with two points, s and t, within the polygon. Is there a polygonal path from s to t that simultaneously minimizes the number of segments and amount of turning. Simple means homeomorphic to a disk; a polygonal path is a piecewise-linear curve; and turning is measured by the sum of the absolute values of the turning angles.

---

I'm making the following restatement of the initial problem, now solved, because it describes the sort of path that I'm investigating. Also the description may trigger insight into the question of bounds on straightness:

*The polygon can be considered as a tunnel in which there is no line of sight between two points, which we can imagine to be the source and destination of a light beam. We seek to install the **smallest number** of light beam relays required to forward a signal as quickly as possible though the tunnel from source to the destination. The locations of the relays are the equivalent to the intermediate vertices of the shortest discrete curve with the minimum possible segment count embeddable in a non-trivial/non-convex polygon.*

Comment: What is your definition of how 'straight' a curve is?

Comment: The total signed curvature. Please refer to page 20 of the following document:
http://ddg.cs.columbia.edu/SIGGRAPH05/Didactic.pdf

Comment: I still don't understand what you are looking for. If I understand, the curve you are looking for is made of concatenated segments, yes?Correct me if I am wrong. Second question, in this case do you want to minimize the sum of the angles (counted as the rotation angle $\theta \in [0,\pi]$, from the input to the output)  at the concatenation points?

Comment: By a "path of polygons" it sounds like you mean "a polygon". Is that correct? Is it correct that you are asking whether there is
a path that simultaneously minimizes the number of segments and
also minimizes the sum of the absolute value of angles? 

Comment: @Christi : I believe the total signed curvature is defined as the sum of the absolute values of the turning angles of the segments, not their signed values.


Comment: @Patrick: yes the curve I'm looking for consists of concatenated segments and yes the initial problem was to minimize the sum of angles. (The rest of this comment is continued in my response to your recent answer.)

Comment: @Bill: yes the "path of polygons" in this case is a polygon, albeit a non-convex one. (The former term is a relic of the domain in which the problem originated.) And yes what I'm asking is if the path that minimizes the number of segments also minimizes the sum of angles. However, in light of Patrick's recent observation that a curve with a longer segment count can be just as straight, the question now is in if a straighter curve exists.

Comment: I'm voting to close.  This is a rather standard problem in computational geometry, which can be solved using Dijkstra's algorithm.  There is a SE site devoted specifically to TCS (http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/), although I am not sure whether they accept such elementary questions.

Comment: @Dmitri: thanks for informing me of the SE TCS site; I can see the ovelap. However the question I'm asking isn't about the shortest path through a graph. I'm aware that Dijkstra's algorithm provides the answer to the problem of the shortest path. Dijkstra however says nothing about the straightness of curves embeddable in a polygon which this is what I'm interested in.

Comment: @Olumide: The question you are asking is exactly about the shortest path through a graph.  The point is that you should first convert your polygon to a weighted graph, then find the shortest path in it, which will be “the straightest path” provided that you choose the right weights for the edges.  I again strongly recommend you to ask this question at the TCS site.  The community there can explain to you how to construct such a graph, if you are not familiar with these techniques.  I want to stress again that this problem is at most at the undergraduate level and therefore unsuitable for MO.

Comment: I am interested to read the solution of this question. Dimitri can you give us a precise link? Thx. 

Comment: @Dmitri: No I am not asking about the shortest path through a graph. If anything, Patrick's diagram makes that abundantly clear. (A shorter curve can have a larger segment count.) In the language of graphs, I am interested in the path with the smallest node count or hops, which in the original problem domain amounts to the curve with the smallest segment count. As to whether this question is best suited to MO, I can only say that it is a computational geometry question which makes it acceptable in MO. I have therefore taggged it as such. Like Patrick I welcome a formal proof of your assertion.

Comment: @Dmitri: I'm aware that Dijkstra's algorithm on a graph with unit weights or an unweighted graph for the edges of the graph will correctly select the longer, two segment path $P_1$ instead of the shorter three segment path $P_2$. This is essentially how I solved the initial problem. The question I'm now aqsking is if there is a path straighter path than $P_1$. I repeat, the problem of the path with the shortest segment count is solved. I am now interested in the question of bounds on the straightness of embeddable curves.

Comment: @Dmitri Pavlov: I find your eagerness to close impossible to understand. If it's so obvious, can you at least tell us the answer? Does there always exist a path that simultaneuously minimises the number of straight-line segments and the 'straightness'?

Comment: @Olumide: Could you please be more precise?  What do you want to optimize and what exactly do you mean by “bounds on the straightness”?  If you mean that you want to minimize the maximum angle or the sum of all angles in the path, then you should just use Dijkstra's algorithm.    As I said before, computational geometry questions are much more sutiable for TCS SE site, not for MO.

Comment: @TonyK: What's so impossible to understand that undegraduate-level questions are unsuitable for MO?  By the way, I started a meta discussion about this question here: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/895/the-straightest-possible-path-embeddable-in-a-path-of-polygons/#Item_1

Comment: @TonyK: If by “straightness” you mean the maximum bending angle of a path, then Patrick I-Z's answer below provides a counterexample.

Comment: @Dmitri Pavlov: That's not a counterexample. The first path simultaneously minimises the number of straight-line segments and the 'straightness' (which is pi/2 for both paths).

Comment: @Dmitri Pavlov: By the way, undergraduate-level questions are often suitable for MO. But in this case, I think you have simply misunderstood what is being asked. That happens to me a lot :-)

Comment: @TonyK: No, I have not misunderstood what is being asked.  If you read one of my previous comments, you can see that I mention both the maximum angle and the sum of all angles as possible meanings of “straightness” and point out that both problems can be solved using Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: @TonyK: If you read the faq, it says “MathOverflow's primary goal is for users to ask and answer **research level math questions**”.  Undegraduate level questions by definition cannot be research level questions.

Comment: @Dmitri Pavlov: Given a piecewise straight path, let's define its 'straightness' as the sum of the absolute values of the turning angles at each vertex. (The turning angle is the amount by which the next segment deviates from the previous segment. I hope this is clear.) Now, given this definition, PLEASE tell me whether the following conjecture is true or not:
Given a simple polygon, and two points P,Q in it, does there always exist a path from P to Q that simultaneously minimises the number of straight-line segments and the 'straightness'?


Comment: Please, stop arguing, or someone gives a clear answer, or a link to a clear answer, or we continue with the question until a) we are tired b) we get an answer. This is the "raison d'être" of this site, I am wrong? The discussion here prove without doubt that it is a research question, since nobody until now has been able to produce a clear and indisputable answer.

Comment: @TonyK: The original question mentions “sequence of polygons”, and it is trivial to construct a counterexample to your statement in this case.

Comment: @Dmitri Pavlov: In that case, please, give us a counterexample.

Comment: @TonyK: Well, consider a polygon with two polygons inside and two points on the boundary.  The path with the shortest number of segments has two segments.  It goes around both inner polygons and makes a turn by π/2 in the middle.  The straightest path goes _between_ two inner polygons, which look approximately like two semicircles, however, their adjacent boundaries are not straight but slightly deformed.  This prevents you from going between them using one or two segments, but you can still pass between them using (say) 10 segments and turning by π/200 (say) every time. 

Comment: @Dimitri I would appreciate a picture. Thx

Comment: @Patrick I-Z: Unfortunately, I do not have enough time to draw a picture.  Which part of my description is unclear?

Comment: @Dmitri Pavlov: I did say *simple* polygon...

Comment: @Dimitri — I don't say that it is unclear, but I may mistake your point, and a picture says so much and immediately. Anyway, I'll try to understand your construction.

Comment: @TonyK: I am answering the original question about “sequence of polygons”, not your modified question about simple polygons.

Comment: @Dmitri Pavlov: I don't think I have violated the intent of the original poster: I have just clarified it. Can you answer my question? I did say 'please'. I don't mind if you can't, but I wish you would admit it :-)

Comment: @TonyK: If you want an answer to your new question, why not post it as a separate question?  I am not trying to answer this question, I am trying to argue that it should be closed because the rules of MO clearly say that only research-level questions are allowed.

Comment: @Dmitri Pavlov: My Socratic method was aimed at showing you that your eagerness to close was misguided. I think I have succeeded in that to the satisfaction of our viewers, but I am disappointed that you remain stubborn. Do you really still think this question has no place here?

Comment: Please stop arguing in this comment thread. Protracted arguments about the suitability of a question belong on meta. If you ever find yourself wanting to "argue back", please post a link to meta instead. 

Comment: @TonyK -- you've hit the nail on the head in more ways than one. @Dmitri Pavlov, for the last time, my question is **NOT** about finding a path. (Let's close that chapter, shall we?) What I would like to know is if the path that minimizes the number of straight-line segments also minimizes 'straightness' (as defined as the sum of the absolute values of the turning angles of the path).

Comment: Sheesh, can someone move all the argumentative stuff somewhere else? This is embarrassing.

Comment: It is not embarrassing, it's real life. Left the commentaries please. It is a lesson for everyone. I hope it will help the people in charge to be more careful next time, before judging if a question has right or not to stay open.

Comment: @Olumide - arex has proposed a reformulation of your question at http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/895/the-straightest-possible-path-embeddable-in-a-path-of-polygons/ - if you agree with this interpretation of your question, would you add it to the bottom of your question as it now stands, as a clarifying remark?

Comment: @David Roberts -- it sounds just about right. I'll add it as clarifying remark.

Answer (score 4):

As a complement to Bill Thurston comment, what situation do you prefer?

http://math.huji.ac.il/~piz/private/Image1.png

In the second case you have more segments but the length is shorter, and obviously the sum of the angles are equal in both cases.

Note: I assume that the ends points are fixed, that is you have no choice on their position on the side of the polygon. Is it OK?

---

*P.S. I couldn't put the figure in the comment, so I put it in an answer even if it is not, it was to long to explain with words.*

---

Addendum:

I am not sure that the process of simplification can help in anything. But I'll try to clarify what I have in mind. Imagine that the bold black curve is the path of minimal length (I didn't draw the ambient polygon). You go from $a$ to $b$ etc. The point $b$ is the first point of "inflection", means that the turning changes sign. If you don't touch the first and last segments on $(a,b)$ you will not change the total turning angle on this piece of path. You have then (on the picture) the choice of three simplifications (thin lines marked with circles at rupture points), two of them gain 1 segment count, and the other one gains 2. If some of them fit in the ambient polygon, it's fine, and you continue that way, on the next part, until the next inflection point. You would like to simplify also by shortcutting along the green dashed line, but you cant since the bold curve is assumed to be the shortest, it must be an obstacle there. So, this way starting with a short curve you may improve the straightness. As I am really not an expert on this kind of geometry, I am not sure this way leads somewhere. It seems that there is still a long way from here to a proof of the existence of what you are looking for.

http://math.huji.ac.il/~piz/private/Image2.png

Comment: This is an perspective on the domain of solutions. I'd naively assumed that a curve with a longer segment count not be as straight but your figure shows that this is possible. The question now therefore is if a straighter curve exists. My primary interest is in determining if the curve with smallest number of segments is (one of) the straightest possible. In which case, no other curve, regardless of segment count, can be straighter. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I'm not sure what it means that a curve would increase the segment count as is currently stated in the question. It would be possible to join the beginning and end points of the path in this example with a semicircle, or in the second example by a quarter circle in such a way that there would be no corners ie tangent continuously defined at every point. How is a segment defined in such a case? I'm confused as to what is being asked, and how straightness is being defined.

Comment: @Mark The curve is made of concatenate affine segments. The "straightness" is defined as the sum of the absolute values of the "turning angles" (the curvatures). Note that, on each convex/concave part of the curve the straightness is just the difference of the angles at the two ends (measured correctly) and the total straightness is the sum of the partial straightness on these elementary sub-curves. It seems that the question is to find an algorithm to minimize the straightness and the segments count simultaneously.

Comment: @Patrick What I seem to be confused about is whether curves are allowed. If we are talking about line segments that is clear. The curves are longer than the segments, but I was not sure whether the segments were straighter than the curves (or as straight as - I think the quarter-circle in the second example is as straight as the segments shown on the definition given, but it is smooth in the sense of having a continuously varying tangent, and I was not sure whether this would make the configuration a single segment when assessing the segment count)

Comment: @Mark — I had the same confusion when the question was asked first, but Olumide made the point precise after one or two comments. Now remark that whenever the curve is smooth or not, on the convex/concave parts the absolute curvature is the same (difference of angles). So it doesn't change much (a priori) to consider a series of affine segments or a series of smooth curves (connected at the "inflection" points), but the affine version is 1) simpler 2) may correspond more to the real world (light beams according to what said Olumide). Or we can suggest to use optical fiber ;-))

Comment: @Mark -- smooth curves, if we assume that they consist of infinitely many line segments, are allowed. They are however suboptimal solutions to the problem because they consist of more line segments than is necessary, even though smooth curves can have the same total curvature as the optimal discrete curve with the smallest possible segment count. (Also, let's not forget that smooth curves are longer than line segments.)

Comment: How about this: if we assume that the shortest path is straightest (no straighter path exists because it would be shorter), it would be sufficient to show that the curve with the smallest segment count is **always** just as straight -- or not. The question now is, under what conditions do two curves that have the same origin and destination have the same total signed curvature? I suspect this has got something to do with convex hulls ...

Comment: I tried yesterday evening to find a counter example to your claim, I couldn't, it makes me believe that you are right. But I have no much time today :(

Comment: @Olumide — It seems to me that, starting with a curve minimizing the length, and simplifying wherever it is possible to decrease the segments count (for example in the figure above: from right to left) when you don't loose in straightness you may "converge" (not sure it converges really) to a solution of your problem. But it is far to be clear, it is just an idea...

Comment: Its a nice idea, and echoes my convex hull idea. (I found the Simplification paper a hard read). Your idea would probably work on my contorted tunnel diagram in the original post. As you noted, the challenge is to (1) prove mathematically that the idea works for all cases and not just the ones we've imagined (2) show that the simplified (least segment) path has the same straightness as the shortest path. 

Comment: The google docs link http://tinyurl.com/48ynyl6 (to a DVI/PDF) shows the visibility graph that I constructed in order to extract the path with the smallest segment count that can be embedded in the tunnel shown in the original post. I haven't bothered to extract the shortest path but, from scratches I made to a printout of the tunnel I'm increasingly convinced that simplification does reduce the shortest path to the path with the smallest segment count. Of course a mathematical proof would be nice :) .

Comment: @Patrick I-Z -- Thanks for the update. I'm a bit more optimistic about simplification. I think its possible to perform simplification beyond $b$ to the unlabeled vertex, which I will call $c$, at the far right end of the path. Locally this simplification will look like a this |_| (but rotated slightly to the left) and will have the same total turning angle as $(b,c)$.

Comment: Yes, now it remains to prove that this process gives you finally a path which minimizes locally the segments count and the straightness. This is another story :) 

Comment: @Patrick I-Z: your previous comment appears to have led to two important conditions *either* of which a minimum-segment count curve (MSCC) must possess in order to be as straight as the shortest curve (SC) -- I'd like to know what you think of this. The first, and the simpler is that segments of both curves all turn in the same direction. Because the MSCC has fewer segments, it forms a hull around the SC as shown in your first diagram. The alternative condition is that both curves share a tangent at each point of inflection (is there actually "a" point of inflection?) ...

Comment: ... So that portions of the MSCC on either side of the point of inflection satisfy the first property as shown in your latter diagram, including my modification of it. The key now is to show that the second condition always holds for non-trivial paths whose segments do not maintain one turning direction.

Comment: @Olumide — Just to clarify: what I called "inflection" points are the points where the turning angle change sign. It may be better to choose another name, I agree (maybe "rupture points"?), the "inflection point" would be before (at the middle of the previous segment?). At these points we don't touch the in/out segments. Between two such points the curve has a fixed convexity/concavity, and we simplify there. But your simplification showed that such "rupture" points can disappear (in this case the point $b$), it is pushed away..

Comment: @Patrick I-Z -- we are in agreement then. I guess all that remains now is to prove that both curves have fixed convexity/concavity between the points of inflection, which as you noted will be at the middle of a special segment whose end points are the rupture points of the MSCC. Better still, it could (not entirely sure) be sufficient to show that this segment is maintained, i.e. not eliminated, by all valid simplifications.

Comment: I am not sure we are going in a good direction, this way. Let us rethink your problem. There exists a piecewise linear curve joining $A$ to $B$ in the polygon which minimize the segment counts, this is clear because the segment counts is an integer. Let us say $N$ is the minimum number of segments. Now, on the set of curves with $N$ segments the straightness has an infimum (since it is a non negative function). First question: is this infimum a minimum?

Comment: Now, if this infimum is a minimum. Second question: does there exists a curve, which necessarily has a greater segment count $N'$, but for which the infimum straightness is less than the previous one. In other words, why the infimum of straightness $\theta(N)$ is smaller than $\theta(N')$?

Comment: Nice formal statement of the problem. Is it okay to produce a sketch proof by considering the two types of shortest curves that can be encountered (those with and without fixed concavity/convexity), and showing that simplifying of both types of shortest curves does not increase the total turning angle.

Comment: Okay, how about this. If the curve with the shortest segment count is a simplification of the shortest curve. The former forms a hull about the latter and cannot introduce "extraneous" curvature, which suggests that the hull has the same total turning angle as the shortest curve from which it is derived. Of course this is plain conjecture.

Comment: A real geodesic is a curve which has zero curvature, I would like to understand what is a "linear piecewise geodesic", does it minimize also the total curvature? I would say yes because the more a triangle is flat, near the line, the smaller is the curvature.

Comment: Yes a linear, piecewise geodesic minimizes the total curvature. BTW, here's a link to an image I put up on google docs showing the minimum-segment curve as a simplification of a shortest path -- http://tinyurl.com/6gasemx .

Comment: I'll think about. I have no much time right now, but I will :)

Comment: BTW both picture links in your answer seem to be dead. (Uploading picture through the editor should create more stable link - an imgur link posted through Stack Exchange account.) I'm just mentioning this since the question has been bumped anyway.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I see. I surely made a mistake and deleted the picture unintentionally :-(

Answer (score 4):

The natural generalization of your "straightest-possible" constraint is a curvature-constrained path.
I know this is not what you asked, but I wanted to mention that even finding a path with maximum
curvature 1 inside a convex polygon is already difficult.  This was studied by
Agarwal     et al. in a paper,
"Curvature-Constrained Shortest Paths in a Convex Polygon,"
([*SIAM Journal on Computing*, Volume 31, Issue 6, 2002](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=586955))
Here is one of their figures, which hints at why it is difficult to find a path between initial $I$ and final $F$
positions/orientations:

[image: Fig5]

Returning to the question (or questions) you *did* ask,
I think looking at the paper
"Polygonal path simplification with angle constraints," by Chen et al.
([*Computational Geometry*, Volume 32, Issue 3, November 2005, Pages 173-187](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6TYS-4F9MTMD-1&_user=10&_coverDate=11%252F30%252F2005&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_origin=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1605134901&_rerunOrigin=google&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=f7541fcdf8f9726493f5ae49471bc907&searchtype=a)), might help.
They explicitly consider the "tunnel" version of your revised question, phrased in terms of an
error tolerance $\epsilon$.  Perhaps most usefully for your purposes, they describe all the related
work in this domain, which has considered many variations.
Usually those variations start with a path $P$, and then try to find another path (a "simplification")
with certain properties: (1) The min-# problem: Find a path that remains within $\epsilon$ of $P$ but has the fewest
segments; (2) The min-$\epsilon$ problem: Given a fixed number $m$ of segments, find a path using
no more than $m$ segments that minimizes $\epsilon$.  This specific paper solves the min-# problem
with the addition of angular constraints, which seems close to your initial formulation (as clarified in the comments).

**Edit**. Here is a preliminary version of the "Simplification" paper: [simplification.pdf](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/MathOverflow/simplification.pdf).

Comment: Unfortunately, the paper is not free :(

Comment: Sorry about that, Patrick. I added a link to a preliminary version.

Comment: The paper shows that the question seems far to be trivial, and the method of simplification for a given path may work (although I am not a specialist of this kind of geometry). It seems to me that there are two parts for solving this kind of questions: the first part would be to guess the good candidates to be simplified, and the point here could be: where to put the inflection points? The second part would consist to the simplification, which seems more feasible algorithmically. I know that this cannot help much. But now, the ball is in the court of the specialists :-)

Comment: The link to `sciencedirect.com` is broken, but the article can be found at [doi:10.1016/j.comgeo.2004.09.003](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.comgeo.2004.09.003) ([Zbl 1082.65018](https://zbmath.org/1082.65018)).

Comment: The link to `cs.smith.edu` also seems to be broken at the moment, but a copy of the PDF is saved at the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506191339/http://www.science.smith.edu/~jorourke/MathOverflow/simplification.pdf).